# Map latest record to an object class by hibernate annotation using condition

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to get only one object mapped by multiple columns.

Simplifying - I have 2 tables:

1) dict_warehouse_item with columns: item_id, date, sequence_prefix and sequence_nb ...

2) warehouse_document_item with columns: ... document_id, item_prefix and item_nb ...

In `warehouse_document_item` table I have no `item_id`, but I have `item_prefix` and `item_nb`. Unfortunately it can point to many version of the item. It doesn't really matter which one I will choose, but I need it to be mapped to only one. Let's say I want it to be the newest (by `date`).

Fallowing code gives out an error:

> "org.hibernate.mapping.Formula cannot be cast to
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Column"

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinFormula(value = "SELECT wi.item_id FROM dict_warehouse_item wi 
 WHERE (wi.sequence_prefix = item_prefix AND wi.sequence_nb = item_nb) 
 ORDER BY wi.date DESC LIMIT 1", referencedColumnName = "item_id")
public DictWarehouseItem getDictWarehouseItem() {
    return this.dictWarehouseItem;
}
```

Can someone help me fix this please.

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: It is hibernate 4.1.7.

Comment: Maybe you should update from an 8 year old version to a newer one. Many bugs have been fixed in the meantime, this might be one of those.

Comment: hey Chrisian, thank you, very good suggestion. Unfortunately I have no option to do it. That suggestion is made but no action there.